# How to write Java generic method with E... elements and return List<E>

Tags: java, generics

I want to write a method as follow

```
public static <E> ArrayList<E> newList(E... elements){
    ArrayList<E> list = new ArrayList<E>(elements.length);
    addAll(list,elements);
    return list;
}
```

It works when I use it like this

```
List<String> a = ListUtils.newList("a","b");
```

But it can't be compile in this case

```
List<Class> c = ListUtils.newList(String.class,Long.class);
```

How can I to fix this problem ?
Thank you !

Comment: This appears to be very similar to an existing utility in guava. http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v17.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList(E...)  If you simply need a List, it is also very similar to `Arrays.asList`  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)

Comment: Always provide the compile error if your question is about a compile error.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you, then you can do that with a wildcard ([jls-4.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1)) like so,

```
public static void main(String[] vargs) {
  List<Class<?>> c = ListUtils.<Class<?>>newList(String.class,Long.class);
}
```

Also, your `newList` wouldn't compile as you posted it. I assume it should be something like,

```
public static <E> List<E> newList(E... elements) {
  List<E> list = new ArrayList<E>((elements != null) ? elements.length : 0);
  for (E elem : elements) {
    list.add(elem);
  }
  return list;
}
```

Comment: `newList` compiles fine...if you static import `Collections.addAll`.

Comment: You need to handle `elements` being null. It would currently result in a NullPointerException.

Comment: `List<Class<?>> c = ListUtils.<Class<?>>newList(String.class, Long.class);` would be preferable if you wanted to add further (non-null) elements to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're getting tripped up on the type inference piece.  It's binding the rest of your elements to a type of `Class extends Comparable & Serializable` (from the compiler error).

You can fix this by adding a wildcard-extends clause to your generic list; you only really care about elements that could actually be assigned as a `Class`.

```
List<? extends Class> c = ListUtils.newList(String.class,Long.class);
```

Comment: Thanks! I also find this statement can be compiled :
List<Class<?>> b = ListUtils.<Class<?>>newList(String.class,Long.class);
So, is it just a "use" problem, not a method problem ?